# diagonalizable square matrices of order $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Can anyone please help me with the following questions:

Let $K $ be a commutative field and $ M_n(K)$  is the vector space on $ K$  of square matrices of order n with coefficients in $K.$

1: prove that any matrix $ M$  in $M_n(K)$  not having $ 0$  as eigenvalue is invertible and give the expression of it's inverse.

2: prove that a nilpotent matrix $ M$  in $ M_n(K) $ is diagonalizable if and only if it is equal to $ 0$ .

3: let $ M $  in $ M_n(K)$  such that $M^3 = I$  where $ I $ is the identity matrix in $ M_n(K)$ , prove that $ M $  is diagonalized

Comment: (1) Use a high-school formula for matrix inverse. (2) I suppose that by *"diagonalised"* you mean *"diagonalisable"*. If so, this part should be trivial. (3) This is false. Consider $M=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ over a field of characteristic $3$.

Comment: hello @user1551 could you elaborate more on the questions because i need to prove them even if they are trivial, thank you for your help

Comment: In (2), if $M$ is diagonalisable, by a similarity transform, you may assume that it is a diagonal matrix. Now think about what diagonal matrices are nilpotent.

Comment: Note (3) even breaks over $\mathbb R$ since $\mathbb R$ isn't algebraically closed

Answer (score 0):

1: maybe it’s useful to know that the characteristc polynomial (I will call it $p_M$) evaluated in the given matrix gives back the zero matrix.
So, let $p_M=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+ a_1 x + a_0$. Now,since $0$ isn’t an eigenvalue we know that $x$ does not divide this polynomial, so we can ensure that $a_0\ne0$.
Now $\mathbf{O}=M^n+a_{n-1}M^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1 M + a_0 \mathbf{I}.$
We now have $\mathbf{I}={a_0}^{-1}(M^{n-1}+a_{n-1}M^{n-2}+\cdots+a_1\mathbf{I})M.$
So this point is proved.

2: a nilpotent matrix has only $0$ as eigenvalue (why?) so a diagonal matrix with all zeroes in the diagonal is the zero matrix.

3: as already pointed in the comments this point is not true if the field is not algebraically closed. For example you can’t diagonalize a generic 2x2 rotation matrix Over the reals, because it’s eigenvalues are complex numbers (check it).